# How do I stub a Class object in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, oop, testing, rspec

I am trying hard to enforce encapsulation (but am probably not doing very well), and want to test the code in Rspec. The Customer class will take a class Object (as klass) when it is instantiated in a factory class. Through an as yet non-existent UI, the Customer will create an Order.

My current test is as follows. I just want to confirm that the order is the Order class.

```
describe 'Customer' do 
  let(:customer){Customer.new}
  let(:customer_with_instantiation){Customer.new(:klass=>order, :name=>'Oscar Wilde', :number=>'0234567')}  

  let(:order){double :order, :name=>:order}

  it 'klass object to be the order class when customer is instantiated with a klass attribute' do
    expect(customer_with_instantiation.klass).to be_a(order)
  end  

end
```

Class code as follows:

```
    class Customer

      attr_accessor :name, :number, :klass

      DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ORDER = {:order_detail => [{ :dish=>"", 
                                                    :item_count=>0 }], 
                                :order_total_cost=>0 }

      def initialize(options={})
        @name=options.fetch(:name, "")
        @number=options.fetch(:number, "")
        @klass=options.fetch(:klass, Object)
        @customer_order=DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ORDER
      end  

      def place_order(menu)
        #requires user input
        customer_order=klass.new({:order_detail => [{:dish => :pizza, :item_count => 3}, 
                                                    {:dish => :burger, :item_count => 3}],
                                  :order_total_cost => 210})
        klass.test_customer_order(customer_order, self)
      end  

    end



  class Order

     attr_reader :order_detail, :order_total_cost
     attr_accessor :total_check 



 def initialize(options={})
    @order_detail=options.fetch(:order_detail, Object)
    @order_total_cost=options.fetch(:order_total_cost, Object)
  end  

  def self.test_customer_order(customer_order, customer, menu, assistant)
    customer_order.total_check = 0
    customer_order.order_detail.each do |order_item|
      menu.dishes.each do |dish|
        if order_item[:dish]==dish.name
          customer_order.total_check += dish.price*order_item[:item_count]
        end  
      end  
    end
    assistant.take_order(customer_order, customer, customer_order.total_check)
  end 

end
```

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want us to help you with? Is the code not performing as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `be_a`, you're testing that `klass` is an instance of `klass`, which is probably not what you want.

It seems to me that when testing the `initialize` method and the getter for `klass` (which is what you're doing, in effect), you should only be interested in confirming that whatever you send into `Customer.new` can be read afterwards.

So maybe something like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :klass
  def initialize(args)
    @klass = args.fetch(:klass)
  end
end

describe Foo do
  describe "#initialize" do
    let(:klass) { double }
    let(:instance) { Foo.new(klass: klass)}
    it "sets klass" do
      expect(instance.klass).to eq(klass)
    end
  end
end
```

Some general points:

- If you want to test whether the order is an instance of `klass`, you should probably rewrite your code to make that easier to test
- `klass` isn't a very useful name in this case. It isn't clear why a `Customer` would need a klass.
- You want to decouple the order from the customer, but the customer is clearly making some assumptions about the interface of the order. Did you really achieve anything?
- I'd recommend not putting test methods in the classes themselves, but rather in the test files.
- Using `Object` as a default in `fetch` is probably not what you want. To begin with, you probably want them to be instances of some class, not class objects.
- Is it really the job of an instance of the `Customer` class to create orders? If the point is to make sure that any kind of abstract order can be instantiated based on user input, maybe a separate `OrderCreator` class would be more appropriate? This class could accept user data and an order class and the affected customer.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, this is very helpful. The OrderCreator suggestion especially may just solve all my problems.